# Understanding the output of PSQL's \dp and \z

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm having trouble selecting from a database in PSQL. This is the output of the table I'm interested in. Can someone decipher the access priveleges for me? I know that `arwdRxt` means append,read,write,etc... The syntax is confusing to me, what exactly do the slashes and equals mean in the access privileges column? Please let me know if my question isn't clear.

```
                    Access privileges
 schema |     name      | type |    access privileges    
--------+---------------+------+-------------------------
 public | table_name    | view | amazonuser=arwdRxt/amazonuser+
        |               |      | readonly=r/amazonuser
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-NOTES

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is described in detail in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-priv.html).  The thing before the = is who has those permissions, the thing after the / is who granted those permissions.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused by the "who granted those permissions" part of the output (I read right over it in the doc),

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE):

```
Privilege   Abbreviation    Applicable Object Types
SELECT      r (“read”)      LARGE OBJECT, SEQUENCE, TABLE (and table-like objects), table column
INSERT      a (“append”)    TABLE, table column
UPDATE      w (“write”)     LARGE OBJECT, SEQUENCE, TABLE, table column
DELETE      d               TABLE
TRUNCATE    D               TABLE
REFERENCES  x               TABLE, table column
TRIGGER     t               TABLE
CREATE      C               DATABASE, SCHEMA, TABLESPACE
CONNECT     c               DATABASE
TEMPORARY   T               DATABASE
EXECUTE     X               FUNCTION, PROCEDURE
USAGE       U               DOMAIN, FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER, FOREIGN SERVER, LANGUAGE, SCHEMA, SEQUENCE, TYPE
```

Comment: The question is specifically not asking about the privilege abbreviations.